# date_default_timezone_set() not set correctly php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, css

the output date of my code below is October 8, 2016 12:35:am but this is not the correct timezone, today is October 7, 9:40:am, anyone can help? thanks a bunch..

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
$time = date('F j, Y g:i:a', time());       
$sql = "UPDATE user SET u_last_login = '$time' WHERE u_id='$id'";
```

Comment: I tried it and it is working fine. https://repl.it/Dq06/0 go to your `php.ini` and check if `date.timezone` is set to `Asia/Manila` and is not a `comment`.

Comment: but my website is not yet in a cloud .. i'm working on it on my local computer server

Comment: Can you confirm you clock on the local server is set correct?

Comment: What version of php are you using?

Comment: yes date and time is set accurately.

Comment: PHP version 5.4.41

Comment: please echo $time just after $time=date('F j,Y g:i:a',time()).If you are still getting the wrong date time,then show us your full php code.

Comment: still having same problem.